Which means property custom_id in discord(pycord)
Which means property custom_id in discord(pycord) and show examples with this property
I do not understand what is where and why it is needed. I have a cat, but I want to understand what the custom_id is for and, if possible, add the code to the bot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Documentation
By custom_id I'm assuming you mean the parameter for button creation. See here.
The custom_id is:

The ID of the button that gets received during an interaction.
If this button is for a URL, it does not have a custom ID.

Source
Usefulness
Have you ever had the problem of past interactable views not being accessible after a bot restart? Well, the custom_id can be useful for this purpose. If we set the custom_id to anything, after the bot restarts it should keep the view saved (if the bot loads the view & the view has no timeout).
Here's some example code:
import os
import discord
from discord.ui import View, Button

# --- Bot Setup ---
bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.listen()  # ensures that it doesn't override the event method that syncs the bot
async def on_connect():
    bot.add_view(EpicView())  # Add the view to make it persistent
    print("Bot is connected!")


class EpicView(View):  # The persistent view
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)  # A timeout of None is required

    @discord.ui.button(
        label="Hello!",
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
        custom_id="hello_button",
    )
    async def hello(self, button: discord.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):  # the button that uses the custom_id to make the persistent view
        await interaction.respond("This works!")


@bot.slash_command()
async def send_view(ctx):  # basic slash command to send the view
    view = EpicView()
    await ctx.respond("Hi!", view=view)

This produces:

Above is the first button press

Above is the second button press AFTER the bot restarted.

What an answer with example

@ChachatonelHashimotto That should be the standard
